# Excel - Multiple IF function use, but need 3 Potential Outcomes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, finance

I need to develop a formula to pull three choices from the STATUS column G: Paid, Unpaid, or Overdue. We're currently trying to use the following formula in a nested IF loop:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(K9),"",IF(K9<TODAY(),"OVERDUE","UNPAID"))
```

But this only gets us halfway. We need to include an option that IF K9 has a value included (will be a date field, but just needs to identify if a value is there) that this takes precedent and notes column G as 'PAID'. We haven't been able to find a way to make this work thus far.

Any thoughts?

[image: Payout Field]

Comment: Where is this formula located, is it Column G? Your formula doesn't include any reference to Column L, but is that how you know whether it was paid or not?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you mean "IF L9 has a value included" (K9 does not make any sense here) the formula should be:

```
=IF(L9<>"","Paid",IF(ISBLANK(K9),"",IF(K9<TODAY(),"OVERDUE","UNPAID")))
```

note: this formula will accept any value in L9 (including a blank space etc.)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this Formula:**

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(K9),K9<TODAY()),"Due",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(K9),K9=TODAY()),"Paid",IF(ISBLANK(K9),"","Unpaid")))
```

**How it works:**

1. The `ISNUMBER` will first check whether the Cell has `DATE` value or not and then whether is `<Today()` or `=Today()` for `DUE` or `Paid`.
2. Next part will check if the Cell is `Blank or not`.
3. Finally if cell `K9` has any `Date` is `Greater than Today()` or even has `TEXT` Formula will display `UNPAID`.